# How to display user output based on the value store in the firebase (Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase

In my firebase, the status is stored as "0", "1", "2", "3". When I fetch the data it is presented in this manner "status: 0". How do I code it such that when I fetch the data it will display "status: new" instead of "status: 0"

component.html

```
        <html>
        <table id="table" class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Due Date</th>
              <th>Assigner</th>
              <th>Assignee</th>
              <th>Urgency</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let content of acts">
              <td>{{content.dueDate}}</td>
              <td>{{content.Assigner}}</td>
              <td>{{content.Assignee}}</td>
              <td>{{content.urgency}}</td>
              <td>{{content.description}}</td>
              <td>{{content.status}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </html>
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from 
"@angular/forms";
import { TodoItem } from "../_models";
import { ToDoListService } from '../_services';

@Component({
selector: "toDoList",
templateUrl: "./toDoList.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./toDoList.component.css"]
})
export class ToDoList implements OnInit {
Form: FormGroup;
currentUser: User;
acts: Array<any> = [];
act: TodoItem;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
private todoSrv: ToDoListService) {
let res2do = todoSrv.getAll();
res2do.then(result2do => {
  result2do.subscribe(async _acts => {
    this.acts = _acts;
    console.log("Initial act", this.acts);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: can you post your current code please

Comment: do you want to show the status as `new` in the table instead of `0`

Comment: @PatricioVargas hey I just added the code please take a look

Comment: @BearNithi Yes that's right

Comment: @BearNithi Thanks for the answer!! what if I have more than one user output? for example "status: New", "status: Pending" and "status: Completed" .

Comment: @EverettT see my answer

Comment: updated the answer for your three status

Comment: I hope it solved your problem effectively.

Comment: @BearNithi Yes, definitely. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this

```
<td>{{content.status === 0 ? 'new' : content.status }}</td>
```

or

**TS**

```
getStatus(status: number): string {
   if(status === 0) {
     return 'new';
   }

  //you can add more user output here
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <td>{{ getStatus(content.status)}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` ternary operator in the interpolation as follows:

```
<td>{{(content.status === 0) ? 'New' : content.status }}</td>
```

If you have more than one status, you should create a method in the component.ts, use switch statement to set the different values based on the status number as follows:

```
getStatus(statusNum) {
  let status = '';
  switch(statusNum) {
    case 0: 
      status = 'new';
      break;
    case 1:
      status = 'pending';
      break;
    case 2:
      status = 'completed';
      break;
   }
  return status;
}
```

component.html

```
  <td>{{getStatus(content.status) }}</td>
```